# TFS 2015 how to manually post a link to a Changeset in team room

Tags: git, tfs, tfs-2015

I can use #workitemID to link to a workitem, and I realised I can add events to add "code changes" to the room.

But how can I manually post a link to a Changeset (or even git commit/push)? I don't want to post the whole URL.

e.g: how can I add the Changeset link like showing in the following picture manually.

[image: Team Room]

Comment: There is a detailed documentation in here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/track/alerts-and-notifications

Comment: @CodeWizard, that is for set up alert, not posting in the team room.

Comment: You have this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/528db562-6155-4887-a7c8-d1745d0260b0/how-to-associate-a-change-set-for-a-work-item-after-code-has-already-been-checked-in?forum=tfsgeneral

Comment: @CodeWizard, thank you again, but I really have no problem of associating a change set (or a Git commit) with a work item. As I said in my question:::::I'm looking for posting a link in the TFS teamroom to link to my changeset/Git commit.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't (I always wondered why not).  It's a good idea for a [Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vsts/collaborate?sortby=downloads&sortBy=Downloads) extension though.

There is a [User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/7552228-allow-to-link-changeset-in-team-room) suggestion from a year ago but it only has one vote.  If enough people vote on it, they'll probably implement it.